# What is the reason to explore and study the Real Analysis Area?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, learning

I repeated 4 analysis classes, this is the 5th time. I believe I'll pass, but I still can't understand Real Analysis. I can understand statistics, numerical analysis, Calculus I-II and even Topology, but can't get real analysis. I think to learn **anything** one must solve problems about that subject all by h{is,er}self, I didn't do that much in Real Analysis but still, I had to have some intuition after all this time. I can understand the definitions but it's not enough.  It's like teacher explains it like you are playing mario but gives a homework similar to hardest game on world.

Level: Undergrad.

For Example: We start with Limit definiton o a sequence, then Corollary and Theorems come about bounded functions, Bolzano-Weierstrass... Etc, Then we study series and I start to lose why do we do this. So I alter my question to "What's the end goal of Analysis? To find functions' properties or how do they act in infinity?" If I knew that I would understand it better.

I quickly lose the track of our purpose. Are we on sequences? OR sequences of functions? Are we on series? I don't know why are we doing this. It's like someone said lets add this elements of a sequence together and call it series.

Any tips and tactics to comprehend this abstract beast of an area? Shortly, I can't "talk" Real Analysis, it's a very hard language for me I haven't cracked. Do you have any textbook recommendation?

Comment: what you mean by "real analysis" exactly? at what level? in any case try to learn from some textbook and make a lot of exercises. You can start reading *Understanding Analysis* of Abbott, IMO is the best introductory book to this subject

Comment: Can you give an example of something specific that you don't understand? E.g. a definition, or a theorem, or a type of problem?

Comment: This was very helpful to me as an undergrad, and I still return to it sometimes when I'm very stuck. There's both general tips for any branch of math and some specific to analysis. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/245a-problem-solving-strategies/

Comment: I suggest you try to write down definitions of basic concepts in your natural language without any math symbols. For example _supremum_ of a set is never exceeded by members of the set but every number less than the supremum is exceeded by at least one member of the set. Also treat Greek symbols like $\epsilon, \delta$ on par with Roman symbols like $a, b, c$ as they are no different. Most of the easy part of analysis is just made difficult by symbolism and formalism. The hard part is all about completeness of reals.

Comment: If you can understand topology, then you can understand real analysis. Topology generalizes real analysis in many ways.

Comment: the core concepts of real analysis are: 1) The concept of limit of a sequence; and  2) The axioms that defines the set of real numbers. This is all, and almost every theorem of real analysis follow from that. As @Paramanand says it is a good practice to understand things just using normal words, without any symbolism.

Comment: It is funny that everybody missed the gist of the question that the original poster does not understand Real Analysis because the original poster does not see the utility of Real Analysis. “Solve problems”, “purpose”, “end goal” all are pointing to this conclusion. If you learn mathematics formally, without knowing its applications, you quickly lose motivation. I can relate to that, so I will try to explain the purpose of Real Analysis.

Comment: Real Analysis, or Analysis in general, not so long ago was called Differential and Integral Calculus and was used to solve differential and integral equations. These equations are needed in many sciences, so I will not recount them. The most prominent of them is physics with its application branch called engineering. But also in social sciences. Economics became much more mathematical recently.

Comment: Analysis is Differential and Integral Calculus based on formal definitions. Historically, the formal definitions of Analysis were invented much later than Calculus. The definitions appeared approximately in 1850, and Calculus appeared in 1700. Before formalization, mathematicians “proved” theorems by physical intuition. Of course, there were mistakes. They were fixed by new generations using this formalization. So the purpose of Analysis, besides all the tasks of Calculus, is to distinguish correct solution methods from those that only seem correct.

Comment: It is easy to lose the perspective in Analysis because a lot of formal reasoning is required to get to solving problems arising, say, in physics. Just the construction of real numbers may fill tens of pages. Analysis is complex, it is how it is. However, from my experience, I would say that this is true for many advanced areas of mathematics. For example, a lot of formal work is required to get from basic definitions of mathematical logic to Gödel's incompleteness theorems.

Comment: In order to keep your motivation high, I would suggest that you keep in mind what applications of Calculus you are interested in, read popular and historical books on Analysis (the only name that I can remember now is Stillwell), and look out for books about applications of Analysis. Probably, your current learning materials and instructors are too heavy on the formal side of Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Your posting gives so little information that the best possible answers may miss what you need to know, but I will hazard these two small points:

You need to understand:

- Proofs: How to judge whether are argument you see on the page is value and how to know what it says; and how to write valid proofs.
- The gaplessness of the real line. Suppose $A\cup B =\mathbb R$ and  $A\ne\varnothing\ne B$ and $A\cap B= \varnothing$ and (important) every member of $A$ is less than every member of $B.$ Then there is a boundary point that is a member of either $A$ or $B$. A **“gap”** would be a pair of sets satisfying these four requirements but in which $(1)$ for every member of $A$ there is a larger member of $A$ and $(2)$ for every member of $B$ there is a smaller member of $B.$ The real line has no gaps.

  This seems to me a more intuitive way to explain the matter than talking about the "least upper bound property."

Comment: I love the Dedekind formulation for completeness (the gaplessness in your answer) more than all the other formulations because it does not use any new terms and operations. If one gets this rest is really easy. +1